# Excluded files from tfs still being checked in

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, wix, wix3.8

I'm currently working on a WiX project and I need to include some files in my project but exclude them from tfs.  I need to do this because these files are auto-generated at compile time but they have to be part of the project to be compiled.  I thought that I could exclude them from source control by going to `File->Source Control->Advanced->Exclude <file> From Source Control` but it still seems to be including it in TFS.

Below is a picture of my project and it appears that visual studio is trying to exclude them from tfs judging by the little red icon next to the files I'm excluding.  However when I compile it errors out because the excluded files are read only and I can clearly see them checked in by looking at the source control explorer window.

[image]

Is this an issue in visual studio or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by closing out my solution and deleting the files in source control explorer.  Before when I was deleting them from source control explorer I had my solution open and it was actually removing them from the project file.  Seems like when you exclude them from source control via the method described above it should remove them from source control but it doesn't.

Comment: Brilliantly useful. Thank you Cole. I searched everywhere to find out how to do this!

Comment: I like this answer, and it worked for me. Simpler than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413389/exclude-from-source-control-not-really-working-in-visual-studio-2013 which probably is the new way.