# Exclude from Source Control not really working in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I've excluded certain files from source control in Visual Studio 2013 via the File > Source Control > Advanced > Exclude From Source Control option. I see the little icon pop up next to my target file that says "Excluded from Source Control" However, every time there's an edit to that same file, IT STILL SHOWS UP IN PENDING CHANGES!

Why? Am I misunderstanding the point of "exclude from version control"?

Comment: Are you using a local workspace or a server workspace?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using local workspaces you should use .tfignore to remove items from the pending changes. The other stuff is to support server workspaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx

You should find the documentation in there but the format is the same as .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

Were the files in the pending list before you exclude them? If so, please perform an Undo operation on the items. Then you can try editing again and they should not show in pending list again.

Comment: nope, they were not. files that weren't in the pending list are reappearing in pending changes even after being excluded